# how to Print pictures/html pages with mono

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I have an app, that hase been written on C# .Net. Today i need take this app, and go to Linux. I build an app with mono C# using gtk#, and everything works except printing. I need to print html page. I found an examle, that explain, how to print (http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnome.gtk%2B.csharp/9244) but when i try to start this app, i catch an exception (system.reflection.targetinvocationexception). I try to create a new app gtk#, that contains window with one button, and with button click create new PrintOperation, but i catch same exception. all that things i do with xamarin studio and windows 10. Please, help me. what am I doing wrong? 
all exception has been catched at line po.Run(PrintOperationAction.PrintDialog, null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, i try and try to find an answer, and this is it!

"I added the following decorator, 
and the issue went away:

[STAThread] 
public static void Main(string[] args) { 
... 
}"

I take it from http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/GtkPrinting-td4661623.html